# Adtf dat files - streams and structure types

Tags: parsing, format, adtf, adtf3

ADTF dat file contains streams of data. In the .dat file there is only a stream name. To find the structure of the stream one has to go through DDL .description file.

Sometimes the .description files are incomplete or are missing link from stream name to corresponding structure.

Is there some additional information about structure name hidden in the .dat file itself? (Or my understanding is completely wrong?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must differ between ADTF 2.x and ADTF 3.x and their (adtf)dat file structure.

**ADTF 2.x:**

You are right, you can only interpret data with ddl. The stream must point to a structure described in Media Description.

> Sometimes the .description files are incomplete or are missing link
>   from stream name to corresponding structure.

You can avoid this by enable the Option Create Media Description in Harddisk Recorder. Then a *.dat.description will be stored next to the same-titled *.dat file, which contains the correct stream and structure reference, because it was available during recording.

> Is there some additional information about structure name hidden in the .dat file itself?

No, it is only the stream name. So you need to know the data structure behind to interpret. If you have the header (c-struct), you can also convert to ddl and refer to that.

**ADTF 3.x:**

To avoid these problems for not available or incorrect description files, the DDL is now stored in the *.adtfdat file in ADTF 3.x

Comment: Thanks! Could you point me to some documentation or blogpost about this adfdat and new DDL schema?

Comment: I couldn't find any ADTF 3 samples on the internet. From the documentation it still looks like there is a description file: https://support.digitalwerk.net/adtf/v3/adtf_html/page_ddl_specification.html Not sure how to interpret that...

Comment: Unfortunaetly there is no documentation of the format available yet and will coming soon. How it will looks like and how you access could be found here: https://support.digitalwerk.net/adtf/v3/adtf_html/page_codec.html

Comment: Additional, I found something in the concept paper which is almost similar: https://support.digitalwerk.net/adtf3_concepts/Concepts_ADTF3.pdf