# ADTF recording file format

Tags: c++, adtf

I am coding an ADTF recording file reader in C++. I have already read the header using the structure specified here
https://support.digitalwerk.net/adtf_libraries/adtf-streaming-library/v2/DATFileFormatSpecification.pdf

```
typedef struct tagFileHeader { 
    int ui32FileId;
    int ui32VersionId;
    int ui32Flags;
    int ui32ExtensionCount;
    long long ui64ExtensionOffset;
    long long ui64DataOffset;
    long long ui64DataSize;
    long long ui64ChunkCount;
    long long ui64MaxChunkSize;
    long long ui64Duration;
    long long ui64FileTime;
    char ui8HeaderByteOrder;     
    long long ui64TimeOffset;
    char ui8PatchNumber;
    char _reserved[54];
    char strDescription[1912]; 
} tFileHeader;   // size is 2048 Bytes
```

I read the heder

```
ifstream file("myfile.dat", std::ifstream::binary);
char buffer[2048];
file.read(buffer, 2048);
const tagFileHeader* header = reinterpret_cast<const tagFileHeader*>(buffer);
```

And now I need to read the chunks. This is the chunks header, extracted from the same document

```
typedef struct tagChunkHeader { 
    long long ui64TimeStamp;
    int ui32RefMasterTableIndex;     
    int ui32OffsetToLast;     
    int ui32Size;     
    short ui16StreamId;     
    short ui16Flags;     
    long long ui64StreamIndex; 
} tChunkHeader;  // size is 32 Bytes
```

Reading the chunks

```
for (int c = 0; c < header->ui64ChunkCount; ++c)
{
    char chunkHeaderBuffer[32];
    file.read(chunkHeaderBuffer, 32);
    const tChunkHeader* chunk = reinterpret_cast<const tChunkHeader*>(chunkHeaderBuffer);
    //Skeep chunk data
    file.seekg(chunk->ui32Size, ios_base::cur);
}
```

I don't know how to interpret the chunk data. Is this specified in another document that I am missing?
Thanks

Comment: Some additional info in the comments to [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50344082/adtf-dat-files-streams-and-structure-types).

Comment: I only have a .dat file with versionID=0x0201

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of completeness:

The chunk data layout depends on the original sample data and the used serialization. So there is not one single data layout. You have to deserialize the chunk data with the correct deserialization implementation and can then interpret the deserialized data with the correct struct definition. The information about the used serialization is stored within the index extension of a stream.

As C-3PFLO has already stated, the adtf_file library does all this for you, but you need all required deserializer plugins.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a example (based on upcoming ADTF File Library 0.5.0) how to access dat files and extend the reader with additional adtffileplugins. Use this read dat files which contains e.g. flexray data recorded with ADTF 2.x:

```
/**
 * @file
 * ADTF File Access example
 *
 * @copyright
 * @verbatim
   Copyright @ 2017 Audi Electronics Venture GmbH. All rights reserved.

       This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla
       Public License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed
       with this file, You can obtain one at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/.

   If it is not possible or desirable to put the notice in a particular file, then
   You may include the notice in a location (such as a LICENSE file in a
   relevant directory) where a recipient would be likely to look for such a notice.

   You may add additional accurate notices of copyright ownership.
   @endverbatim
 */

#include <adtf_file/standard_adtf_file_reader.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>

// initalize ADTF File and Plugin Mechanism
static adtf_file::Objects oObjects;
static adtf_file::PluginInitializer oInitializer([]
{
    adtf_file::add_standard_objects();
});

void query_file_info(adtf_file::Reader& reader)
{
    using namespace adtf_file;

    //setup file version
    uint32_t ifhd_version = reader.getFileVersion();
    std::string adtf_version("ADTF 3 and higher");
    if (ifhd_version < ifhd::v400::version_id)
    {
        adtf_version = "below ADTF 3";
    }

    //begin print
    std::cout << std::endl << "File Header" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "File version      : " << reader.getFileVersion() << " - " << adtf_version << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Date              : " << reader.getDateTime().format("%d.%m.%y - %H:%M:%S") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Duration          : " << reader.getDuration().count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Short description : " << getShortDescription(reader.getDescription()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Long description  : " << getLongDescription(reader.getDescription()) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Chunk count       : " << reader.getItemCount() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Extension count   : " << reader.getExtensions().size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Stream count      : " << reader.getStreams().size() << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl << "Streams" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;

    auto streams = reader.getStreams();

    for (const auto& current_stream : streams)
    {
        auto property_stream_type = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<const PropertyStreamType>(current_stream.initial_type);
        if (property_stream_type)
        {
            std::string stream_meta_type = property_stream_type->getMetaType();      
            std::cout << "Stream #" << current_stream.stream_id << " : " << current_stream.name << std::endl;
            std::cout << "    MetaType       : " << stream_meta_type << std::endl;

            property_stream_type->iterateProperties(
                [&](const char* name, 
                const char* type,
                const char* value) -> void
                {
                    std::cout << "        " << name << " - " << value << std::endl;
                });
        }
    }
}

class StreamsInfo 
{
    typedef std::map<uint16_t, std::chrono::microseconds> LastTimesMap;
    typedef std::map<uint16_t, std::string> StreamNameMap;

    public:
        StreamsInfo(adtf_file::Reader& reader)
        {
            auto streams = reader.getStreams();
            for (auto current_stream : streams)
            {
                _map_stream_name[current_stream.stream_id] = current_stream.name;
                UpdateType(current_stream.stream_id, current_stream.initial_type);
            }
        }
        ~StreamsInfo() = default;
       std::string GetDiffToLastChunkTime(const uint16_t& stream_id, const std::chrono::microseconds& current_time)
        {
            return GetLastTimeStamp(_map_last_chunk_time, stream_id, current_time);
        }
        std::string GetDiffToLastSampleStreamTime(const uint16_t& stream_id, const std::chrono::microseconds& current_time)
        {
            return GetLastTimeStamp(_map_last_stream_time, stream_id, current_time);
        }
        std::string GetStreamName(const uint16_t& stream_id)
        {
            return _map_stream_name[stream_id];
        }

        void UpdateType(const uint16_t& stream_id, const std::shared_ptr<const adtf_file::StreamType>& type)
        {
            auto property_stream_type = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<const adtf_file::PropertyStreamType>(type);
            if (property_stream_type)
            {
                 _map_stream_meta_type[stream_id] = property_stream_type->getMetaType();
            }
        }
        std::string GetLastStreamMetaType(const uint16_t& stream_id)
        {
            return _map_stream_meta_type[stream_id];
        }

    private:
        std::string GetLastTimeStamp(LastTimesMap& map_last_times,
                                                   const uint16_t& stream_id,
                                                   const std::chrono::microseconds& current_time)
        {
            std::chrono::microseconds result(-1);
            LastTimesMap::iterator it = map_last_times.find(stream_id);
            if (it != map_last_times.end())
            {
                result = current_time - it->second;
                it->second = current_time;
            }
            else
            {
                if (current_time.count() != -1)
                {
                    map_last_times[stream_id] = current_time;
                }
            }
            if (result.count() >= 0)
            {
                return a_util::strings::format("%lld", result.count());
            }
            else
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
        LastTimesMap _map_last_chunk_time;
        LastTimesMap _map_last_stream_time;
        StreamNameMap _map_stream_name;
        StreamNameMap _map_stream_meta_type;
};


void access_file_data(adtf_file::Reader& reader, const std::string& csv_file_path)
{
    using namespace adtf_file;

    //load stream information
    StreamsInfo stream_info(reader);

    std::cout << std::endl << "File data" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;

    utils5ext::File csv_file;
    csv_file.open(csv_file_path, utils5ext::File::om_append | utils5ext::File::om_write);

    //set the labels
    csv_file.writeLine("stream;stream_name;chunk_type;stream_type;chunk_time;samplestream_time;chunk_time_delta_to_lastofstream;samplestream_time_delta_to_lastofstream");

    size_t item_count = 0;
    for (;; ++item_count)
    {
        try
        {
            auto item = reader.getNextItem();
            std::chrono::microseconds chunk_time = item.time_stamp;

            std::string chunk_type;
            auto type = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<const StreamType>(item.stream_item);
            auto data = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<const Sample>(item.stream_item);
            auto trigger = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<const Trigger>(item.stream_item);
            std::chrono::microseconds sample_time(-1);
            std::string sample_time_string("");
            if (type)
            {
                //the type change is part of the 
                chunk_type = "stream_type";
                stream_info.UpdateType(item.stream_id,
                                       type);
            }
            else if (data)
            {
                chunk_type = "sample";
                auto sample_data = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<const DefaultSample>(data);
                if (sample_data)
                {
                    sample_time = sample_data->getTimeStamp();
                    sample_time_string = a_util::strings::format("%lld", sample_time.count());
                }
            }
            else if (trigger)
            {
                chunk_type = "trigger";
            }

            csv_file.writeLine(a_util::strings::format("%d;%s;%s;%s;%lld;%s;%s;%s",
                static_cast<int>(item.stream_id),
                stream_info.GetStreamName(item.stream_id).c_str(),
                chunk_type.c_str(),
                stream_info.GetLastStreamMetaType(item.stream_id).c_str(),
                chunk_time.count(),
                sample_time_string.c_str(),
                stream_info.GetDiffToLastChunkTime(item.stream_id, chunk_time).c_str(),
                stream_info.GetDiffToLastSampleStreamTime(item.stream_id, sample_time).c_str()
                ));
        }
        catch (const exceptions::EndOfFile&)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    csv_file.close();
}

adtf_file::Reader create_reader(const a_util::filesystem::Path& adtfdat_file_path)
{
    //open file -> create reader from former added settings
    adtf_file::Reader reader(adtfdat_file_path,
                             adtf_file::getFactories<adtf_file::StreamTypeDeserializers,
                                                     adtf_file::StreamTypeDeserializer>(),
                             adtf_file::getFactories<adtf_file::SampleDeserializerFactories,
                                                     adtf_file::SampleDeserializerFactory>(),
                             std::make_shared<adtf_file::sample_factory<adtf_file::DefaultSample>>(),
                             std::make_shared<adtf_file::stream_type_factory<adtf_file::DefaultStreamType>>());

    return reader;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 3 || argv[1] == NULL || argv[2] == NULL)
    {
        std::cerr << "usage: " << argv[0] << " <adtfdat> <csv> [<adtffileplugin> ...]" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    //set path for adtfdat|dat and csv file
    a_util::filesystem::Path adtfdat_file = argv[1];
    a_util::filesystem::Path csv_file = argv[2];

    try
    {
        //verify adtf|dat file
        if (("adtfdat" != adtfdat_file.getExtension())
            && ("dat" != adtfdat_file.getExtension()))
        {
            throw std::runtime_error(adtfdat_file + " is not valid, please use .adtfdat (ADTF 3.x) or .dat (ADTF 2.x).");
        }

        //verify csv file
        if ("csv" != csv_file.getExtension())
        {
            throw std::runtime_error(csv_file + " is not valid, please use .csv for sample data export.");
        }

        //check for additional adtffileplugins
        for (int i = 3; i < argc; i++)
        {
            a_util::filesystem::Path adtffileplugin = argv[i];
            if ("adtffileplugin" == adtffileplugin.getExtension())
            {
                adtf_file::loadPlugin(adtffileplugin);
            }
        }

        //setup reader
        auto reader = create_reader(adtfdat_file);

        //print information about adtfdat|dat file
        query_file_info(reader);

        //export sample data
        access_file_data(reader, csv_file);
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return -2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the code that I was using. I just need to download the flex ray deserializer plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why you try to reimplement an ADTF DAT File Reader ? It will be provided by the ADTF Streaming Library and should provide to access any data stored in a dat file. See the File Access Example (https://support.digitalwerk.net/adtf_libraries/adtf-streaming-library/v2/api/page_fileaccess.html) how to use the reader as well as the API itself and all other examples.

Hint: You can also use the successor - ADTF File Library with the same possibilities but with two more benefits: Complete Open Source to see how the (adtf)dat file handling works and also support for files created with ADTF 3.x. See https://support.digitalwerk.net/adtf_libraries/adtf-file-library/v0/html/index.html

Comment: I have tried to read the file using ADTF File Library provided by DigitalWerk.net but obtained this exception in the adtf_file::Reader constructor:
_no type deserializer for 'adtf.type.flexray.adtf2_support.serialization.adtf.cid' available_. Where can I download the code of the library?

Comment: Well, getting an error or an exception does not mean to reimplement something different. This message is easy: The reader does not know how to deserialze the data from ADTF 2.x flexray stream type in your recorded file, so you have to provide it (as always). So you have to extend the reader by adding the deserializer plugin provided by Device Toolbox. Use https://support.digitalwerk.net/projects/download-center/repository/changes/adtf-toolboxes/adtf-device-toolbox/release-3.0.0/dev_tb_3_0_0_patch_for_adtf_3_4_0.zip in combination with ADTF File Library 0.4.x or higher.

Comment: Thanks, I have just sent and email to support@digitalwerk.net in order to register at the Digitalwerk community and for downloading the flexray deserializer plugin provided with the Device Toolbox. Just to understand, the format specification of the ADTF file is not completely open? I don't find a clear answer to this question anywhere.

Comment: The format is open and publish, I just want to recommend you to use the provided libraries, so you don't have to reinvent the wheel. Also if there is something missing for you you can do it by yourself in ADTF File Library, the examples are only demos which shows how things going on. For format see https://support.digitalwerk.net/adtf_libraries/adtf-streaming-library/v2/DATFileFormatSpecification.pdf and https://support.digitalwerk.net/adtf/v2/adtf_sdk_html_docs/page_a_utils_indexedfileformat.html, for adtfdat from ADTF 3.x it is still missing but that is not relevant for your use case.

Comment: Thanks, I don't want to reimplement anything, I am just understanding which are my options. I don't find the format of the chunk data. Do you know where it is specified?

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in downloading the streaming Library, here follows the link

https://support.digitalwerk.net/projects/download-center/repository/show/adtf-libraries/adtf-streaming-library/release-2.9.0